# Walk through a nested array using index in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I want walk through a nested array and need to find the target element in the array. An example path `[2, 1]` should return `{text: 'More 2'}` and path `[2, 2, 1]` should return `{ text: 'Other-2' }`.  I tried lodash functions but no luck yet.
My Nested array is given below:

```
var data = [
  { text: 'Item 1', },
  { text: 'Item 2', },
  {
    text: 'More',
    children: [
      { text: 'More 1', children: [] },
      { text: 'More 2'},
      { text: 'Other', children:[ {text: 'Other-1'}, {text: 'Other-2'}, {text: 'Other-3'} ] }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: I have tried looping the array  e.g array.forEach(element => { a = arr[element];
           console.log(a)
           if(a.children != null && a.children.length){
              arr = a;
           }else {
             result = a;
           }
          });

Comment: You should put your code that doesn't work into the question along with comments about what isn't working...that will help a great deal in allowing people to tell you what is wrong with your code (which is what this site is good for) rather than what to write.

Comment: @Beska my full code is little complex and pasted here the minimum line of code to sort out the specific problem. I need a simple JavaScript function that can take array of indexes e.g var = indexesToCheck = [2,2,1]; and it should loop though this nested array and expected element is { text: 'Other-2' }. Remember, given indexes are actually sequence to reach that specific element in array.

Comment: Right...you posted the minimum code in the question that sets up some sample data, which is good.  But in order to get quality answers, you usually should post the code that is having trouble as part of the question...it looks like you did part of this in your first comment.  That code should be part of the question as it gives people the chance to see what you're trying to do, and what may be missing or wrong with your approach.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, it's not a multi-dimensional array, nor is it a raggedy array-of-arrays. It's an array of objects (that happen contain other arrays of objects that happen to...).

Lodash's [`_.get()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) ought to do the trick for you:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const data = data = [
  { text: 'Item 1', },
  { text: 'Item 2', },
  {
    text: 'More',
    children: [
      { text: 'More 1', children: [] },
      { text: 'More 2'},
      { text: 'Other', children:[ {text: 'Other-1'}, {text: 'Other-2'}, {text: 'Other-3'} ] }
    ]
  }
];

const widget = _.get(obj, '[2].children[1]');

console.log('widget',widget);
```

Or... roll your own. It's not that hard to walk the tree:

```
function select(data, ...path) {
  let i    = path.shift() ;
  let node = data[i] ;

  while ( node && (i=path.shift()) !== undefined ) {
    node = node?.children?.[i] ;
  }

  return node ;
}

const widget = select( data, 2, 1 );
console.log(widget);
```